# Two Probability Questions from Interview Book

Tags: probability, order-statistics

I'm reading an interview book called A Practical Guide to Quantitative Finance Interivew / Chapter 4 Probability Theory. So I ask those following questions (**I highlighted my doubts in bold**) in this Mathematics Section:

1. Assume that $X_1, X_2, ...$ and $X_n$ are independent and identically-distributed random variables with uniform distribution between 0 and 1. What is the probability that $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +....+X_n\leq 1$?

Solution to question 1: When $n = 1, P(S_1\leq1)$ is 1. As shown in Figure 4.6[image] when $n=2$, the probability that $X_1+X_2\leq1$ is just the area under $X1+X2\leq1$ within the square with side length 1 (a triangle). So $P(S_2\leq1) = 1/2$. When $n=3$, the probability becomes the tetrahedron ABCD under the plane $X_1+X_2+X_3\leq1$ within the cube with side length 1. The volume of tetrahedron ABCD is $1/6$ So $P(S_3\leq1) = 1/6$ Now we can guess that the solution is $1/n!$ To prove it, let's resort to induction. Assume $P(S_n\leq1) = 1/n!$. We need to prove that $P(S_{n+1}\leq1) = 1/(n+1)!$. Here we can use probability by conditioning. Condition on the value of $X_{n+1}$, we have $P(S_{n+1}\leq1) = \int_0^1f(X_{n+1}))P(S_n\leq1-X_{n+1})dX_{n+1}$, where $f(X_{n+1})$ is the probability density function of $X_{n+1}$, so $f(X_{n+1})=1$. But how do we calculate $P(S_n\leq1-X_{n+1})$? The cases of $n=2,n=3$ have provided us with some clue. For $S_n\leq1-X_{n+1}$ instead of $S_n\leq1$, we essentially need to shrink every dimension of the n-dimensional simplex from 1 to $1-X_{n+1}$. So it's volume should be $(1-X_{n+1})^n/n!$ instead of $1/n!$. **So my doubt is: I don't understand why shrinking every dimension of the n-dimensional simplex from 1 to $1-X_{n+1}$ gives the result $(1-X_{n+1})^n/n!$? What is the reasoning behind this?**

2. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with uniform distribution between 0 and 1, $Y = min(X_1,X_2), Z = max(X_1,X_2)$. What is the cumulative distribution function of $YZ$:

Solution to question 2: when $0\leq z\leq1, 0\leq y\leq z$, $F(y,z)$ is the shadowed area in Figure 4.7[image: image2]
**I don't know why the shadowed area in the screenshot? represented $F(y,z)$**